# How to setup cakephp site on XAMPP

Tags: php, cakephp, internal-server-error

I have downloaded a PHP site developed in cakephp and now trying to set up it in XAMPP.

I was having some problems related to .htaccess and cakephp path. I renamed .htaccess files to 1.htaccess and defined hard coded path of cake root folder in one of the .php files so those errors are gone. But now I get new error which is:

> HTTP ERROR 500

How do I display full error so I know exactly what's going on?

Display Errors setting is already defined in php.ini

> display_errors = On

Directory structure is as follows. May be I am not trying to access correct file? I am trying to access:

```
http://localhost/mysite/public_html/app/
```

Even if I try to access webroot, get same error

```
http://localhost/mysite/public_html/app/
```

Directory structure given below.

[image]

[image]

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: I think you should not rename .htaccess file..because this file redirects http calls to cakephp index file which then passes your request to controller...so instead renaming .htaccess file figure it out the exact issue

Comment: If I don't rename .htaccess file then I get same HTTP ERROR 500 and I don't know how to display detailed error.

Comment: I dont know how to enable error reporting in cakephp..but using PHP way is like using these two lines in index file   error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1); .. Additionally you can also check apache error log file

Comment: first clear cache from tmp folder, and don't rename .htaccess

Comment: @FrankMartin What is CakePHP version, 1.x? You need to access http://localhost/mysite/public_html

Comment: Access url till folder not app - 
http://localhost/mysite/public_html/

Comment: I don't think public_html is web root because it contain index.php which has static content (I opened it in notepad and saw its just text). You will notice there is a folder in "app" called "webroot" which to me looks like web root folder but I haven't used cakephp before so I am not sure.

Comment: @FrankMartin put copy of cakephp site in D:\xampp\htdocs\example.com\    and visit localhost/example.com | YES, in cakephp app webroot where you store assest (img, js, css, ...), there is also index.php   wich is same file when you visit localhost/example.com/index.php.  :htaccess make redirect your request from server root (ex, example.com) folder to webroot folder. It's simple.